# Where does the smoke (or vapour?) in engineering come from?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In Star Trek Discovery, episode 3x09, there is a scene about 16 minutes into the episode where Stamets is in engineering. The computer announces: "Video rendering complete", whereupon Stamets steps over to a computer terminal.

In the moment when we see Stamets looking (from the viewer's perspective) to the left, while the terminal is just about out of sight on the left edge of the screen, some smoke is rising from the terminal:

[image: smoke/vapour in Discovery's engineering]

**Where does that smoke/vapour come from, and why is no-one bothered by it?**

Comment: Most IT equipment contains [magic smoke](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke). It's usually a bad thing if it escapes.

Comment: @Valorum: I thought so, too - that's why I was so baffled to see it on the episode, apparently without it being made an issue on-screen nor taken out in post-production or by retaking the scene in the first place.

Comment: Newton's Third Law of Physics: there is no smoke, except that there first be fire.

Comment: Could you provide an image?

Comment: @SovereignInquiry: Done.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Great!

Comment: Off-camera: "Smoke 'em if you've got 'em!"